# Migrate Jooomla installation to new server

Tags: joomla, upgrade, php, php7

Having a terrible time when changing server and updating Joomla and Civicrm. Apologize for the length of this post, but thought is would be helpful to anyone who can address my issues. 
Here's the scoop:
Currently running Joomla 3.6.5 with Civicrm 4.6.33 on a PhP 5.6 server. Had problems with Mailchimp integration and Paypal standard transactions were not updating (new transactions completed at Paypal showed as "Pending". Without detailing all the steps (and following instructionsF, I set up a mirror site on another server with a blank installation of civi and joomla, on Php 5.6. Was able to import existing DB (same db name, userid, etc. and changings to civicrm.settings) with a LOT of trouble, but although Joomla runs fine and I can get to the Civi dashboard, reports generate no contacts, although an individual contact can be edited.

Skipping over the last several weeks of trying, applying patches and upgrading to Joomla 3.7x and Civi 4.7x (tried various builds of each in combination) and switching to PhP 7.0. No go. Moved back on PhP 5.6. In each instance, software update for Civi succeeds, but database upgrade fails.

Next try was to take Akeeba .jpa file and install in new subdomain. Joomla front and back ends work, but Civi functions return errors. Based on logs (most recent below) I'm trying to isolate DB issues. I have even tried editing database tables using PhPMyAdmin to correct errors identified in logs (table structure confirmed by a clean install of Civi 4.7.29 without import of existing data)

Still stuck. In all cases, the website runs correctly except for any Civi functions (like Membership contribution page).

Another weird problem - logs indicated that civicrm_payment_processor table was missing new fields that were added in Civi 4.7x. I tried renaming existing table, then importing correct table, first with structure and data without foreign key checks, then just table structure. Would not create table. Solution was to manually create table using Civi 4.7 structure and populating with one processor (paypal standard). Solved that error message but another one popped up. ANY help would be most appreciated - I have spent mucho time debugging and haven't touched the original PayPal IPN issue.

Here's the latest log:

---

```
Feb 05 18:07:06  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -19
    [message] => DB Error: no such field
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.data_type as `data_type`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_locked as `is_locked`
FROM civicrm_option_group a
WHERE (a.data_type IS NOT NULL)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.data_type as `data_type`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_locked as `is_locked`
FROM civicrm_option_group a
WHERE (a.data_type IS NOT NULL)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.data_type as `data_type`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_locked as `is_locked`
FROM civicrm_option_group a
WHERE (a.data_type IS NOT NULL)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list']"]
)

Feb 05 18:07:06  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(945): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#3 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#4 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list'")
#7 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#9 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#10 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#11 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(369): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#12 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1318): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...", TRUE)
#13 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/SelectQuery.php(143): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `...")
#14 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/utils.php(1254): Civi\API\SelectQuery->run()
#15 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/OptionGroup.php(44): _civicrm_api3_basic_get("CRM_Core_BAO_OptionGroup", (Array:4))
#16 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_option_group_get((Array:4))
#17 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#18 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
#19 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(43): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("OptionGroup", "get", (Array:4))
#20 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/OptionGroups.php(42): civicrm_api3("OptionGroup", "get", (Array:4))
#21 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component.php(54): CRM_Utils_Check_Component_OptionGroups->checkOptionGroupValues()
#22 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php(209): CRM_Utils_Check_Component->checkAll()
#23 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php(93): CRM_Utils_Check::checkAll()
#24 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php(218): CRM_Utils_Check->showPeriodicAlerts()
#25 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DashBoard.php(69): CRM_Core_Page->run()
#26 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Contact_Page_DashBoard->run((Array:2), NULL)
#27 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#28 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#29 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#30 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#31 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(394): require_once("/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/ci...")
#32 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(369): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/ci...")
#33 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(98): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#34 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php(156): JApplicationAdministrator->dispatch()
#35 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(265): JApplicationAdministrator->doExecute()
#36 /home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/index.php(51): JApplicationCms->execute()
#37 {main}


Feb 05 18:07:06  [info] 
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#1271 (8) {
    ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=>
    array(6) {
      ["error_code"]=>
      string(13) "no such field"
      ["sql"]=>
      string(332) "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.data_type as `data_type`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_locked as `is_locked`
FROM civicrm_option_group a
WHERE (a.data_type IS NOT NULL)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list']"
      ["tip"]=>
      string(62) "add debug=1 to your API call to have more info about the error"
      ["is_error"]=>
      int(1)
      ["error_message"]=>
      string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
      ["debug_information"]=>
      string(332) "SELECT a.id as `id`, a.name as `name`, a.title as `title`, a.description as `description`, a.data_type as `data_type`, a.is_reserved as `is_reserved`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.is_locked as `is_locked`
FROM civicrm_option_group a
WHERE (a.data_type IS NOT NULL)
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.data_type' in 'field list']"
    }
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(23) "DB Error: no such field"
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(94) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(45)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(17) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(125) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/OptionGroups.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(42)
        ["function"]=>
        string(12) "civicrm_api3"
        ["args"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "OptionGroup"
          [1]=>
          string(3) "get"
          [2]=>
          array(4) {
            ["sequential"]=>
            int(1)
            ["data_type"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["IS NOT NULL"]=>
              int(1)
            }
            ["options"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["limit"]=>
              int(0)
            }
            ["version"]=>
            int(3)
          }
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(112) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check/Component.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(54)
        ["function"]=>
        string(22) "checkOptionGroupValues"
        ["class"]=>
        string(38) "CRM_Utils_Check_Component_OptionGroups"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(102) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(209)
        ["function"]=>
        string(8) "checkAll"
        ["class"]=>
        string(25) "CRM_Utils_Check_Component"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(102) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Check.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(93)
        ["function"]=>
        string(8) "checkAll"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Utils_Check"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(100) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(218)
        ["function"]=>
        string(18) "showPeriodicAlerts"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Utils_Check"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [5]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(113) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DashBoard.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(69)
        ["function"]=>
        string(3) "run"
        ["class"]=>
        string(13) "CRM_Core_Page"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [6]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(102) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(309)
        ["function"]=>
        string(3) "run"
        ["class"]=>
        string(26) "CRM_Contact_Page_DashBoard"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "dashboard"
          }
          [1]=>
          NULL
        }
      }
      [7]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(102) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(84)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "runItem"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          &array(13) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(3) "176"
            ["domain_id"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["path"]=>
            string(17) "civicrm/dashboard"
            ["title"]=>
            string(12) "CiviCRM Home"
            ["access_callback"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              string(19) "CRM_Core_Permission"
              [1]=>
              string(9) "checkMenu"
            }
            ["access_arguments"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(14) "access CiviCRM"
              }
              [1]=>
              string(3) "and"
            }
            ["page_callback"]=>
            string(26) "CRM_Contact_Page_DashBoard"
            ["breadcrumb"]=>
            array(1) {
              [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["title"]=>
                string(7) "CiviCRM"
                ["url"]=>
                string(63) "/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&amp;task=civicrm&amp;reset=1"
              }
            }
            ["is_ssl"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["weight"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["type"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["page_type"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["page_arguments"]=>
            bool(false)
          }
        }
      }
      [8]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(102) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(52)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "_invoke"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "dashboard"
          }
        }
      }
      [9]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(86) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(121)
        ["function"]=>
        string(6) "invoke"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            [0]=>
            string(7) "civicrm"
            [1]=>
            string(9) "dashboard"
          }
        }
      }
      [10]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(86) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(40)
        ["function"]=>
        string(14) "civicrm_invoke"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [11]=>
      array(4) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(72) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/component/helper.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(394)
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(86) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php"
        }
        ["function"]=>
        string(12) "require_once"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(72) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/component/helper.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(369)
        ["function"]=>
        string(16) "executeComponent"
        ["class"]=>
        string(16) "JComponentHelper"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(86) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php"
        }
      }
      [13]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(81) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(98)
        ["function"]=>
        string(15) "renderComponent"
        ["class"]=>
        string(16) "JComponentHelper"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "::"
        ["args"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(11) "com_civicrm"
        }
      }
      [14]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(81) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(156)
        ["function"]=>
        string(8) "dispatch"
        ["class"]=>
        string(25) "JApplicationAdministrator"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [15]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(71) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/libraries/cms/application/cms.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(265)
        ["function"]=>
        string(9) "doExecute"
        ["class"]=>
        string(25) "JApplicationAdministrator"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [16]=>
      array(6) {
        ["file"]=>
        string(61) "/home/jgsny/public_html/jgsny_restore/administrator/index.php"
        ["line"]=>
        int(51)
        ["function"]=>
        string(7) "execute"
        ["class"]=>
        string(15) "JApplicationCms"
        ["type"]=>
        string(2) "->"
        ["args"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
```